# Given 5 variables, all independently normally distributed, what is the probaility that variable A is lower than the other 4 variables?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, extreme-value

Suppose variables A B C D and E are independent, normally distributed, with known variance and mean.

What is the probability that A is less than B and C and D and E?

Essentially, I have model estimates of a horse's predicted run time in a race. I want to convert these times to a probability of winning - and do this in a closed form way, rather than using simulation methods as I have 10s of thousands of observations.

I understand the way to do this for two variables: P(X<Y) = P(X-Y<0) - but can't figure out how to generalize this to more than two variables.

Comment: While I believe you can find tables and code for probabilities of specific regions in 4-variate correlated normals $(A-B,A-C, A-D, A-E)$, personally, I'd just simulate this. I do question whether a normal model will be sufficient for this application